# json output and cflocation not playing nicely

Tags: json, coldfusion, cfml

This may be a dumbass question but I have a ColdFusion script that outputs some json that hooks into a mobile app - all good, works a dream.

But due to another requirement I now need to forward the page to a php script for some other processing - after the json output. A simple `cflocation` would have worked in theory but now my app says it cant find the json output.

What am I missing? Does a page have to be stopped on the json output or can it be forwarded?

Comment: you can't both output json AND redirect. The redirect likely needs to occur at the front-end.

Comment: ok fair enough - thanks for the confirmation :)

Comment: You could use cfhttp to make a request to your PHP file. You could also use the response from that request and output it.

Comment: To @KevinB's point. have your JSON include the URL that is needed for the redirect and have the client handle it after it processes the data portion of the JSON response.

Comment: @Redtopia suggestion is worth trying. You can make a cfhttp request to the php for further processing before final json output.

Comment: thanks everyone for your input - I went and did a separate call in the end and split them both out